# Session variable resets after a while

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm doing a website where I'm storing data on a variable that is declared like `if (Session["array"] == null) { Session["array"] = new int[30]; }`

And, to use the variable, I call it like `int[] array = (int[])Session["array"];` and then use it like this (its an example of his usage):

```
if (button13.Checked)
            {
                cont++;               
                array[2]++;
            }
```

But for whatever reason, after a while, all of the indexes of the array go back to 0 (this on the website already, not on localhost).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you need it forever, why are you storing it in session?

Comment: @mjwills how should I store them? A static variable will not work.

Comment: Why will a static variable not work?

Comment: Because, if there is more than 1 user, it will overflow and not work

Comment: Where is your session state stored?

Comment: @mjwills dunno. To be honest, I don't know what is that. Can you give me some insight plz?

Comment: Review the session state modes and choose the one most appropriate for your situation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)  It sounds like you want SQL Server Mode which will not clear when the application is restarted, and makes that information available across multiple web applications if needed.

Comment: @hijinxbassist question is, will SQL Server Mode stop the variable refreshing?

Comment: By "refreshing" I am guessing you mean the variable being set to null.  It will maintain the session state since the state is being saved in a database (outside of the web process) and will survive most scenarios.